# Nunit testing if first element of list is instance of class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've made a list which can contain elements of an interface type:
List <ICar>.

I have two car classes which implement the ICar interface, SlowCar and FastCar.

I've made a method which either adds a SlowCar or FastCar to the list, and now I want to test if the first element in the list is an instance of the SlowCar class. Is there a way to do this in Nunit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var yourList = sut.GetList();
var first = yourList.First();
Assert.IsInstanceOf<SlowCar>(first);
```

FYI: Here's the [NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=typeAsserts&r=2.5)